# Php Split array based vales

Tags: php

**Input:**  Given the array of dynamic values .

For EX:

i=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);

**Expected Output:** (array of i)/n

**For EX:(array of i/3)**

1)1,2,3

2)4,5,6

3)7,8,9

How to do this

Thanks

Comment: Please check the [php docs about array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php#refsect1-function.array-chunk-examples)

Answer (score 0):

Am Not getting your point but you can try like this

```
$sourceArray = Array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');
$arr1 = array_slice($sourceArray, 0, (count($sourceArray)/2));
$arr2 = array_slice($sourceArray, (count($sourceArray)/2));


print_r($sourceArray);
//========= FIRST ARRAY ============;
echo"first array";
echo "</br>";
echo $arr1[0].','.$arr1[1].','.$arr1[2].','.$arr1[3];
echo "</br>";

//========= FIRST ARRAY ============;
echo"scond array";
echo "</br>";
echo $arr2[0].','.$arr2[1].','.$arr2[2].','.$arr2[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Mono  You can do like this

```
$sourceArray = Array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');

 $list=$sourceArray;
 $p=3;


    $listlen = count($list);
    $partlen = floor($listlen / $p);
    $partrem = $listlen % $p;
    $partition = array();
    $mark = 0;
    for($px = 0; $px < $p; $px ++) {
        $incr = ($px < $partrem) ? $partlen + 1 : $partlen;
        $partition[$px] = array_slice($list, $mark, $incr);
        $mark += $incr;
    }
    print_r($partition);
```

Comment: @Mano M did you check this example ?